# Android Studio USB Debugging Phone Display Error

Tags: android

I started using the USB debugging mode on Android Studio and when i run my project the display on the phone is completely wrong. The ide displays the correct way i want it to look but when i open the app on the phone the app's displayed contents are all thrown into the top of the screen. Why is it doing this? Sorry for huge picture btw.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using `ConstraintLayout`, but you haven't set any vertical constraints for your views. Therefore, when you run the app, all the views are jumping to the top. Click on the red exclamation mark, it will show you the same thing. Go to the code view, it will also show you the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use minimum 2 constraints from top or bottom nd start or end
It will help you views to attach each other